# Background image is off-setting the page at low resolutions (causing horiz. scrollbar)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overlay, layer

My site shows a large background image layer, with a semi-transparent green layer overlaying it. The problem occurs at lower resolutions, namely the green layer's width seems to get thinner than the background image, thus exposing some of the background image on the right-side of the browser window.

[Here is a link to my demo site](http://taskbasket.net/public/demo11.html)

I can't insert images yet, but [here is a link](http://taskbasket.net/public/screeny.png) to a screenshot displaying what I'm talking about.

The green layer's css:

```
#mainarea {

height: 960px;
width:100%;
  background:rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.7);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}
```

the background image's css:

```
.bg{

    background:url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1415871989540-61fe9268d3c8?q=75&fm=jpg&s=d4ccd3c8661437d6e3ea5e88c63c647f) no-repeat top left;
background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:900px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an element (the h2 in the div with class mainarea) that extends beyond the width of the main area, because its text consists of a very long word that can't wrap. So there are several solutions:

- you can set the h2 to have "overflow: hidden"
- you can set the mainarea div to have "overflow: hidden"
- you can change the h2 title to real text that will wrap correctly

Comment: I think the solution is to use loremipsum.com and input better FPO text.

Comment: Thanks for your input but the problem persists... I have reduced the length of the text in h2, and added overflow: hidden; to h2 (as you can see in Inspect Element), but it still doesn't work. You can see the updated screenshot here: http://taskbasket.net/public/screeny2.png and my site again is: http://taskbasket.net/public/demo11.html. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, now I see that with a lower window width the issue still happens in my browser. Now it is because of the orange button and the email input text in the footer. The problem seems to be that you are giving them a width of 100% and they also have paddings or margins somewhere in the hierarchy that make them exceed the size of their parent. I'd suggest you start by adding "overflow-x: hidden" to the "html" element so that nothing will stick out and try to fix the widths of the elements that don't fit.

Comment: thanks nacho. I seem to have patched it up by adding a min-width specification to the green overlay layer, and also to each of the sections that were protruding to the right. They all line up now (on my real site). Perhaps this isn't the ideal solution though... thanks for your time.